# Checking out TortoiseSVN files onto a server that does not have SVN to create a working files directory

Tags: svn, remote, tortoise-svn, coldfusion

We have a svn server that is a small machine for source control only.  My group is working on a ColdFusion project.  I installed TortoiseSVN 1.8.7, build 25475- 64bit.  I can checkout the repository (324 Mb; approx. 1,600 files) to a local folder with no problem.  I can add files, edit, commit, update, etc. no problem.  However, my local box does not have ColdFusion installed on it.  We have a networked "sandbox" server that has ColdFusion on it.  When I try to checkout the repository on that server I get a crash message with: problem 72258 - dump group:159166 - dump:2192378.  Which seems to indicate that I need to roll-back to a earlier version.  Is this true?  Do I need to install TortoiseSVN on the Sandbox server to get it to work?  Can I get SVN\TortoiseSVN to work on a remote server that does not have TortoiseSVN on it?

Please exuse my ignorance with SVN as I am not used to using it in a networked environment that does not have TortoiseSVN on each machine.

Comment: We decided to drop SubVersion and go with Git; it seems more complex at first; but with further understanding it will work better for our distributed work flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this TSVN's ticket](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisesvn/issues/detail?id=647) history you can

- Return to release `1.8.4, Build 24972`

or

- Wait until building of [nightlies](http://nightlybuilds.tortoisesvn.net/latest/x64/full/) will be restored

or

- Don't use Subversion checkout|update as deploy tool and deploy changesets to CF-server using any other possible tools and transports (FTP|SSH|...)